# Special characters remove?

Tags: salesforce

How to  remove special characters from a string in apex.

Code:
selectedStatus = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('ideaStatus');

value: ideastatus = "We like's it"

I want to remove the ' from the value of ideastatus.

I am trying  selectedStatus.replace("'","");

But its not working.

Can anybody suggest how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
selectedStatus.replace('\'', '')
```

However please note that "We like's it" is grammatically incorrect - it should be "We like it". So you shouldn't have to worry about the apostrophe in this case.

Comment: I know its an wrong statement.. I just used it as an example... I also tried this.. but of no use... It's creating double space "We likes  it"

Comment: What do you mean by double space? Are you sure you're not putting in a space when you replace it, like this: replace('\'', ' ') instead of replace('\'', '')?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pass and get accurate values from URL you, should URL encode and decode those values. URLEncode and URLDecode methods will handle for all special characters.